# How to link a line of code from a typescript file to a markdown README.md file

Tags: typescript, hyperlink, markdown, code-documentation

I'm documenting this api, and I came across one file containing a lot of calls to another service. While writing a detailed documentation for each function, I struggled to link the specific line of code where the function is located (the file is close to 1200 lines of code)

I've tried several things..

```
*  [My Boring Function](./api-calls.ts) // This will link to the file only
*  [My Boring Function](./api-calls.ts#376) // Obviously won't work since theres no html tags.
*  [My Boring Function](./api-calls.ts~376)  // ERROR : File does not exist.
```

I've also tried the YAML syntax `(./api-calls.ts#/376)`. Nothing.

So my question would be, how can I refer to a specific place in a TypeScript file from a Markdown file? Is there even a way to do it? Thanks in advance for the time and patience!

Comment: That depends entirely on how `api-calls.ts` is rendered when that page loads. If it doesn't have anchors defined there's no way to link to a specific part of it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to render the TypeScript files as HTML with line anchors (or equivalent JS URL fragment-parsing behavior).

In your server code, check the [`accept`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept) header to make a determination about whether the client wants html or not, and respond with the html version of the TypeScript file if so, and otherwise respond with the raw text.

Some examples of sites which do this are:

- [GitHub](https://github.com/denoland/deno_std/blob/0.120.0/encoding/toml.ts#L16)
- [deno.land/std](https://deno.land/std@0.120.0/encoding/toml.ts#L16)